How to test a service layer in spring with mockito?
I mocked repository and service. I used when().thenReturn() method with verify but it seems that repository and service are null. For both mocked service and repository the value returned by calling findById(2L) is my custom Exception . What I am missing?
GameCategoryServiceUnitTest.java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GameCategoryServiceUnitTest {
    public static final String CATEGORY_NAME = "detective";
    @Mock
    private GameCategoryRepository gameCategoryRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    private GameCategoryService gameCategoryService;

    @Mock
    private GameCategoryMapper gameCategoryMapper;


    GameCategory existingGameCategory;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        existingGameCategory = GameCategory.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .name(CATEGORY_NAME)
                .build();

    }

    @Test
    void whenCallingFindById_shouldReturnGameCategory() {
        String name = "cooperative";
        GameCategory gameCategory = GameCategory.builder()
                .id(2L)
                .name(name).build();

        GameCategoryDto gameCategoryDto = GameCategoryDto.builder()
                .name(name)
                .id(2L)
                .build();

        when(gameCategoryRepository.findById(2L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(gameCategory));

        // When
        GameCategoryDto result = gameCategoryService.findById(2L);

        //then
        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(name, result.getName());

        verify(gameCategoryRepository).findById(2L); // Verify that the findById method was called
    }
}

application-test.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem/unit_test_db
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    database: H2
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    test:
      database:
        replace: none

I've checked configuration but it seems ok. What else I can check?
Update:
GameCategoryService
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;


import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class GameCategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private GameCategoryRepository gameCategoryRepository;
    private GameCategoryMapper mapper;

    public List<GameCategoryDto> findAll() {
        return gameCategoryRepository.findAll().stream()
                .map(mapper::fromGameCategoryToGameCategoryDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public GameCategoryDto findById(long gameCategoryId) {
        GameCategory gameCategory = gameCategoryRepository.findById(gameCategoryId).orElseThrow(() ->
                new EntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException.ENTITY_GAME_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND_BY_ID + gameCategoryId));
        return mapper.fromGameCategoryToGameCategoryDto(gameCategory);
    }

    public GameCategoryDto findByName(String name) {
        GameCategory gameCategory = gameCategoryRepository.findByName(name).orElseThrow(() ->
                new EntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException.ENTITY_GAME_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND_BY_NAME, name));
        return mapper.fromGameCategoryToGameCategoryDto(gameCategory);
    }

    public GameCategoryDto createGameCategory(GameCategoryUpdateDto gameCategoryUpdateDto) {
        if (gameCategoryRepository.findByName(gameCategoryUpdateDto.getName()).isPresent()) {
            throw new EntityAlreadyExistsException(EntityAlreadyExistsException.GAME_CATEGORY_AlREADY_EXISTS_MESSAGE, gameCategoryUpdateDto.getName());
        }
        GameCategory gameCategory = mapper.fromGameCategoryDtoToGameCategory(gameCategoryUpdateDto);
        GameCategory savedGameCategory = gameCategoryRepository.save(gameCategory);
        return mapper.fromGameCategoryToGameCategoryDto(savedGameCategory);

    }

    public GameCategoryDto updateGameCategory(long gameCategoryId, GameCategoryDto update) {
        GameCategory gameCategory = gameCategoryRepository.findById(gameCategoryId)
                .orElseThrow(()
                        -> new EntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException.ENTITY_GAME_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND_BY_ID, String.valueOf(gameCategoryId)));

        GameCategory gameUpdated = mapper.fromGameCategoryDtoToGameCategory(update);
        GameCategory savedGame = gameCategoryRepository.save(gameUpdated);
        return mapper.fromGameCategoryToGameCategoryDto(savedGame);

    }

    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteGameCategory(long gameCategoryId) {

        GameCategory gameCategory = gameCategoryRepository.findById(gameCategoryId)
                .orElseThrow(()
                        -> new EntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException.ENTITY_GAME_CATEGORY_NOT_FOUND_BY_ID, String.valueOf(gameCategoryId)));


        gameCategoryRepository.deleteById(gameCategoryId);
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .build();
    }
}

GameCategoryRepository.java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface GameCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<GameCategory, Long> {


    Optional<GameCategory> findByName(String name);

    Optional<GameCategory> findById(long id);
}

StackTrace
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.failNull(AssertNotNull.java:49)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:30)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:304)
    at com.adaland.springsecurity.service.GameCategoryServiceUnitTest.whenCallingFindById_shouldReturnGameCategory(GameCategoryServiceUnitTest.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)


Try to use @MockBean

You don't need the setup method, the mocks are managed by the mockito extension that you've applied and you don't need to construct a new existingGameCategory for every test.  Can you share what your service implementation looks like?  Also, @MockBean will not solve this because this test is not using the Spring context (referencing the previous comment).

@lane.maxwell just updated

Thanks, @Hekima.  Could you please include the actual stack trace as well?  From the test I can see that it would return null, but don't see why the repository would not return the gameCategory that you asked it to.  I actually see lots of issues in this service, is this the full definition?

@lane.maxwell I've updated code for service and added stack trace from running the test.

I now see why your test is failing, though it's not failing with your custom exception so I'm unsure where you see that at.
First off, you need to make a change to your service because when this service is instantiated, the mapper will always be null.  You need to add @Autowired to this field in your service.  Your test is working because @InjectMocks will use reflection to set this.
@Autowired
private GameCategoryMapper mapper;

As to your test, it is failing because the response is null, not because the service is throwing your custom exception.  It is null because the response from your service is coming from the mapper, which you've mocked out but never defined behavior on.
Here is your test fully implemented, I believe this should work for you.
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class GameCategoryServiceUnitTest {
    @Mock
    private GameCategoryRepository gameCategoryRepository;

    @Mock
    private GameCategoryMapper gameCategoryMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    private GameCategoryService gameCategoryService;

    @Test
    void whenCallingFindById_shouldReturnGameCategory() {
        String name = "cooperative";

        GameCategory gameCategory = GameCategory.builder()
                .id(2L)
                .name(name).build();

        GameCategoryDto gameCategoryDto = GameCategoryDto.builder()
                .name(name)
                .id(2L)
                .build(); 
        
        when(gameCategoryRepository.findById(2L))
                .thenReturn(Optional.of(gameCategory));

        // This is the part you are missing, and it defines what is returned from your method
        when(mapper.fromGameCategoryToGameCategoryDto(gameCategory))
            .thenReturn(gameCategoryDto);

        GameCategoryDto result = gameCategoryService.findById(2L);

        // I would make a single assertion here, that my result is what I expect.
        assertThat(result, is(equalTo(gameCategoryDto)));

        // verify(gameCategoryRepository).findById(2L); 
        // You don't need this verify, if the method invocation didn't occur, your test would have failed
    }
}

